# How to know when text is copied from a specific textfield in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, touch

I have some textFields which are editable. when user selects its text copy and paste menu items are shown.
I want to know when user taps on the copy. because I want to change the copied text.
Is it possible?

**More details:**
I want to change the copy of 3 textfields. I want to concatenate all these 3 textfields texts into clipboard when one of the textfields are copied. There are other textfields in this page too but I don't want to do anything for them.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. but I have problem with the starting point. I want to be notified when the user taps on the copy but I could not find solution for this.

Comment: Please include what have you researched so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `copy()` method to "intercept" the copy operation and modify what gets placed on the clipboard.

Easiest way is probably a simple subclass of `UITextField`:

```
//
//  MyTextField.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/29/19.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and

```
//
//  MyTextField.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/29/19.
//

#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

- (void)copy:(id)sender {

    // debugging
    NSLog(@"copy command selected");

    // get the selected range
    UITextRange *textRange = [self selectedTextRange];

    // if text was selected
    if (textRange) {

        // get the selected text
        NSString *selectedText = [self textInRange:textRange];

        // change it how you want
        NSString *modifiedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prepending to copied text: %@", selectedText];

        // get the general pasteboard
        UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

        // set the modified copied text to the pasteboard
        pb.string = modifiedText;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get copied string from Clipboard and update to clipboard before paste.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged),
                                               name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification , object: nil)

@objc func clipboardChanged() {
    if let clipboardString = UIPasteboard.general.string as? String {
        // Update string as per your requirement
        let myString = textfield1.text! + " " + textfield2.text! + " " + textfield3.text! + " Append String"
        textfield1.text = myString
        textfield2.text = myString
        textfield3.text = myString
        print(myString)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but clipboard might be changed by other textFields other than these 3.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the exact issue?  as This answer is satisfying the question what you have posted here.

Comment: I am sorry my question was not completed. I updated it

Comment: Can you please check updated answer ! if it fits for your solution